# Get text inside selected element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating an application using `jQuery`  and I am using a swipe left handler. When  I swipe left on a `'li'` element and use:
`console.log($(event.target).text());`.

I get the following in console 
`<li class=​"list-group-item">​ <span class=​"badge">​Italian​</span>​ "IHOP" </li>​`

I need to get `"IHOP"` to proceed. I am unable to find that. I have used

`console.log($(event.target).find('.list-group-item').text());`

but it gives me nothing. However, if I use `console.log($(event.target).find('.badge').text());`.

I get  `Italian`. What is the sorcery here !

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Given the structure, you almost certainly want to use `this` rather than `event.target`. I don't know about swipe handlers, but you would certainly want that if it were a `click` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to get "IHOP" to proceed.

It sounds like you want the text directly contained by the `li` and not the text contained by any descendant elements. Here's one way:

```
var theText = $(event.target).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();
```

*(See alternative below as well.)*

That uses [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) to get the contents of the element (including child elements, text nodes, and comments), then [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to filter out everything except the text nodes (`nodeType === 3`), then [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) to get that text as a string.

You might well want to add [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) in there to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace, so:

```
var theText = $.trim($(event.target).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text());
```

---

Alternative:

In your example markup:

```
<li class=​"list-group-item">​ <span class=​"badge">​Italian​</span>​ "IHOP" </li>​
```

...the text you want is always the *last* node within the `li`, so if that's reliable, you can do this instead:

```
var theText = $.trim($(event.target).contents().last().text());
```

---

If you can't rely on it being the last item, and this is something you need to do frequently, you could add a plug-in to do it, like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.immediateText = function(trim) {
        var rv = this.contents().filter(onlyTextNodes).text();
        if (trim) {
            rv = $.trim(rv);
        }
        return rv;
    };

    function onlyTextNodes() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then to use it:

```
var theText = $(event.target).immediateText(true);
```

Comment: Is there a smaller code for this ? @157247 ?

Comment: @user3257902: I've added an alternative. Hatsjoem's answer also works and one could argue it's shorter than my first example above, although not shorter than the alternative. So you might use that if you can't rely on the text you want being the last node (my "alternative" above).

Comment: @t-j-crowder , your alternative doesn't work

Comment: @user3257902: Yes, it does: http://jsbin.com/kalulowo/1 It may be that you want `this` rather than `event.target` (see comment on question).

Answer (score 3):

```
$(event.target)
     .clone()    //clone the element
     .children() //select all the children
     .remove()   //remove all the children
     .end()      //again go back to selected element
     .text();    //get the text of element
```

Comment: Which question you are trying to answer

Comment: The question he asked, on how to get IHOP without the child elements text.

Comment: Question contains no element with id `foo`

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, don't use jQuery where you don't have to. If writing a function, a simple [*jsperf test*](http://jsperf.com/jquery-get-get-text-vs-pojs) shows the following in mostly plain js will run about 3 times faster than the accepted answer:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn. childText = function () {
      var children = this[0].childNodes;
      var text = '';
      for (var i=0, iLen=children.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        if (children[i].nodeType == '3') {
          text += children[i].data;
        }
      }
      return text;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

and the following plain javascript is 6 to 10 times faster, depending on the browser:

```
// Return the text of the child text nodes of an element,
// but not descendant element text nodes
function getChildText(element) {
  var children = element.childNodes;
  var text = '';
  for (var i=0, iLen=children.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (children[i].nodeType == '3') {
      text += children[i].data;
    }
  }
  return text;
}
```

and use it like:

```
var theText = getChildText(event.target);
```